# Add gradient to Navigation Container in React Native App

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to add a linear gradient as a background to my react native app.

Here is my initial code:

```js
<NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Camera"
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: { elevation: 0 },

        }}
      >
```

And here my attempt at adding the gradient:

```js
const MyTheme = {
    colors: {
      primary: "rgb(255, 45, 85)",
      background: () => <LinearGradient colors={["red", "blue"]} />,
    },
  };
```

Now, when I `console.log(MyTheme.colors)` I get `background: [Function background`

Any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, may help below code.

```
<LinearGradient
  colors={["red", "blue"]}
  start={{x: "Your postition", y: "Your postition"}}
  end={{x: "Your postition", y: "Your postition"}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<LinearGradient style={{ position: "absolute", 
       left:0,right: 0, top: 0,bottom: 0,
        }}
        colors={["#120318", "#221a36"]}
      />
</View>
```

If you set the LinearGradient's position to absolute, and set left,right,top,bottom as 0, LinearGradient will take up entire space's of its parent element.